# How do you perform a recursion on the rest of the first of a list? (Racket)

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, racket

If you have a list of list of lists, how do you access the rest of the first of the list?

e.g. If you have

```
(define l1 (list (list (list 1 1) (list 2 3) (list 7 8))
            (list (list 2) (list 3 4 5))))
```

How would you perform a recursion on this part

```
(list (list 1 1) (list 2 3) (list 7 8))
```

When I try `(rest (first l1))`

e.g. `(map add1 (rest (first l1))`

I get an error `add1: expects a number; given (list 2 3)`

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting to your question?

Answer (score 2):

You're exactly right that the code

```
(rest (first l1))
```

produces the rest of the first of the list.  Specifically:

```
(define l1 (list (list (list 1 1) (list 2 3) (list 7 8))
            (list (list 2) (list 3 4 5))))

(rest (first l1))
```

produces

```
(list (list 2 3) (list 7 8))
```

It's true that you can't add the elements of this list together, because they're not numbers.

Does this answer your question?